# How to use premake with a vs2017 Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, lua, premake

I have a Qt project with Visual Studio 2017. I tried to generate project files with premake and used the premake5.lua file from this page "https://wiki.qt.io/Premake_Project_Manager". this file uses a qt-support.lua module which is available on github. However, when I build my project with premake it shows the following error "qt-support.lua:707: action "qt" needs a description". Next, I download the example repository that is referenced in the official Qt documentation (https://github.com/annulen/qt-examples-premake) and tried to generate the project files for that. Even with their repository, it shows the same error. I haven’t used premake before and so I might probably be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

https://github.com/dcourtois/premake-qt

I've been using it for years and I'm very happy with it.